# Fast Extraction from Raster Datasets using Points - How to speed up the raster::extract() function

Tags: r, parallel-processing, extract, raster

I need to extract values from large RasterLayer (a Digital Terrain Model or DTM), using XY coordinates. Coordinates are in another large data.table.

```
> DTM
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 93690, 74840, 7011759600  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 16, 16  (x, y)
extent     : -80000, 1117440, 6448080, 7947120  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=utm +zone=33 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs 
source     : dtm_16x16_utm33.tif 
names      : dtm_16x16_utm33 
values     : -6.648066, 2273.72  (min, max)

> XY
                x       y
        1: 986488 7930296
        2: 986504 7930296
        3: 986536 7930296
        4: 986552 7930296
        5: 986488 7930280
       ---               
454986003:  61832 6451208
454986004:  61848 6451208
454986005:  61864 6451208
454986006:  61912 6451208
454986007:  61928 6451208
```

extract() function from raster r package could do the task. According to the package manual, the code would be:

```
Altitude <- extract(DTM, XY)
```

##### This, however, takes a long time!!

---

I have tried using the following line of code to run the function in parallel.

```
beginCluster(30)
Altitude <- extract(DTM, XY)
endCluster()
```

However, I can see that of the 64 available cores, only 1 is being used by R, the code is not running in parallel, and the function continues to take a long time.

##### Any ideas how I can speed this up?

---

Note1: I have successfully used lines of code similar to this one...

```
beginCluster(20)
raster3 <- projectRaster(raster1, crs=crs(raster2))
endCluster()
```

...and the server has worked with multiple cores at the same time.

Comment: Have a look to `exactextractr` package. It will be way faster.

Comment: Billy34, package description says "Title Fast Extraction from Raster Datasets using Polygons"... I am interested in extraction by using points.

Comment: Good point. Your data are a bit huge and I strugle to build an equivalent to test against. I would then suggest you to have a look at `terra` package which is a kind of rewrite of package `raster`. Adapting code is fairly straightforward (use rast() for raster() to load your DTM and extract function is the same)

Answer (score 0):

One of the fastest solutions is to use the velox package.
https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/velox/versions/0.2.0

```
library("velox")
library("raster")
library("sp")
library("rgeos")

## convert XY data to SpatialPoints
XY <- SpatialPoints(coords = XY)

## create a velox object from the original raster
DTMV <- velox(DTM)

## fast extraction of altitude data
Altitude <- DTM1V$extract_points(sp = XY)
```